# Filling DataGridView with SQL Database in VB.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am getting an error stating "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'The option 'IntegratedSecurity' is not currently supported." On the line of my connection string, any ideas for how to fix? I am simply trying to fill my DataGridView at the moment in visual studio.

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vbconnectionfinal;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    Dim Adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TrueTrack.UserName", connection)

    Adapter.Fill(Table)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?  Because you have SQL Express as your Data Source and yet you're using a MySqlConnection.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: Still a bit confused, am I unable to use my database since it comes from Sql MS?

Comment: You can't use MySqlConnection with MS SQL Server.  You need to use [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Got it! Thank You!!